# How can I draw a text in my view?

Tags: iphone

How can I draw a text in drawRect?

Answer (score 2):

The NSString class has several methods for drawing itself.
Look in the docs for NSString(UIStringDrawing).

Answer (score 2):

Example:

```
NSString *test = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"test"];
[test drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(200,200) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:23 ]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at the CoreGraphics functions for doing this, though, Jongsma's method tends to be a little easier to use.  Look at the apple docs for the NSString UIKit additions.